# Change specific characters in large string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Sorry for my bad English.
So i have a problem. my need is to replace  specific characters in each string of a string array. Every change must be unique. Problem is that array contains 10000 elements. I know only how to change symbols in specific range of elements, but i can't figure out how to use loop correctly to do this. Here is what I came up with so far:

```
String str1 = "String that contains 100+ symbols";
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(str1);
var replace = strBuilder.Replace('a', 'b').ToString();
stringArray = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 500) select replace).ToArray();
```

Well as i said. I have one string then i have to fill an array that contains 10000 elements with this string.Then I have to make replace or change some characters in each string. Replace shall not be repeated, each string must be unique but should not have large differences from initial string. I need this for my further work.

Comment: I believe your question is unclear. Please provide a little more code to get the context. And sample desired input/outputs.

Comment: I have string array that contains 10000 identical strings. In each string I have to raplace some cahracters. Each replacement must be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the replacement as key value pairs into a `Dictionary`, and apply each replacement by iterating the pairs:

```
var replacements = new Dictionary<char, char>();
replacements.Add('a', 'b');
// add other pairs...

for(int i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i++)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(stringArray[i]);
    foreach(var kvp in replacements)
    {
        sb.Replace(kvp.Key, replacements[kvp.Key]);
    }
    stringArray[i] = sb.ToString();
}
```